# remove() and hide() in a single jquery statement

Tags: jquery

I want to remove some textboxes with same class and a button element with id in a single jquery statement. I tried the following-

```
thisCheck.closest('form').find('.class').remove().find('#id').hide();
```

But only .class elements are removed and #id element not.

Any help?

Comment: Check out [`.end()`](http://api.jquery.com/end/)

Comment: It won't work, you can't find ID from removed element. Use `end()`

Comment: `thisCheck.closest('form').find('.class').remove().end().find('#id').hide();`

Comment: as `$('#id')` is the best and fastest way to select one element by id, you'd really better have two statements. You should not do `something.find('#id')` at all.

Comment: @putvande, make it an answer so that i can accept. Your code works for me.

Comment: @dystroy - agreed, there's no good reason to go out of once way to make one-liners

Comment: @SKPaul Do you realize that Benjamin mentionned `end` before putvande ? BTW I maintain it should not be used in this specific case.

Comment: @dystroy Some guys just prefer to copy/paste code i guess...

Comment: @adeneo Sorry a little confusion happened..! since `find('.class').remove()` points `.class`, surely .end() will point `.closest('form')`..! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you insist on using a oneliner you can do :

```
thisCheck.closest('form').find('.class').remove().end().find('#id').hide();
```

Check the [`end()`](http://api.jquery.com/end/) documentation